# have one handler to serve as the handler for two non-parallel 'try'

Tags: java

Just a short question.

I want to do something like:

```
try{
    //Section A
    ....
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    try{
     //Section B
     .....
    }
}
catch (SQLException e){
    ....
}
```

What I want is to have `catch (SQLException e)` as the handler for both section A and section B. But the aforementioned way is not interpreted by javac.

How can I do it in a wise and gentle way?

One way I can think about is like following:

```
try{
try{
    //Section A
    ....
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
     //Section B
     .....
}
}
catch (SQLException e){
    ....
}
```

Is this the right way?

Thanks for all help.

Comment: First couple of try catch blocks are invalid and doesnt make sense

Comment: Why not simplify by breaking out whatever you are doing in Section B to its own function

Comment: But A and B share the same SQLException handler..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you are doing in your proposed solution is in the first try block so if a `SQLException` is thrown anywhere in that block it will be caught by `catch (SQLException e) {}`